# Stop a event from bubbling in GWT

Tags: java, events, gwt

I have the following snippet of code, changeTextArea is a TextArea object.

```
changeTextArea.addKeyboardListener(new KeyboardListenerAdapter()
  public void onKeyPress( Widget sender, char keyCode, int modifier){
    //do something
    //I WISH TO STOP THE EVENT THAT MAPS TO THIS KEYPRESS FROM BUBBLING ANY FURTHER
  }
}
```

How would I stop the Event that is causing this method to be called from bubbling up from changeTextArea into the Panels/Widgets/Composites/Whatever that contain changeTextArea. Put succinctly, how do I stop it from bubbling any further. Any help would be appreciated (especially code samples).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do it via a keyboard listener, but it is possible by adding an event preview using the DOM class:

```
DOM.addEventPreview(EventPreview preview)
```

Then when you get the event:

```
onEventPreview(Event event)
```

You should return false, to say you want to cancel the event. The Event object also supports this method:

```
public final void cancelBubble(boolean cancel)
```

Cancels bubbling for the given event. This will stop the event from being propagated to parent elements.

You can find more details here:
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/index.html?overview-summary.html

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely use the Event's cancelBubble() and preventDefault() methods from within any code that has access to the Event. There's no need to have an event preview...

Answer (score 2):

You can call the sender's cancelKey() event. Here's an example that will only allow numbers to be inputted, all other keys get rejected.

private class RowColChangeHandler implements KeyPressHandler
    {

```
    public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
        char keyCode = event.getCharCode();
        if(keyCode <48 || keyCode >57)
        {
            ((TextArea)event.getSource()).cancelKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could reach it when possible by doing
`event.doit = false`

Comment: Maybe some explanation would make your answer more useful :)